# Windows command line - write N characters to file with > operator

Tags: windows, command-line

Could you please tell if it is possible to write to a file N characters using > operator

```
echo "helloooooo" > file.txt
```

will write the whole string, is there a way to write just "he" for example?

Comment: Try `> file.txt echo(he`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL enableextensions
set "_write=helloooooox"
> file.txt (
  rem Extract only the first 2 characters: he
  echo(%_write:~0,2%
  rem Extract only the last 3 characters:  oox
  echo(%_write:~-3%
  rem etc. etc.
)
```

Read *entire* `set /?` or [Variables: extract part of a variable (substring)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)